# Can't store ftp zip file with Laravel and Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, storage

When I try to save a zip file from ftp, the file is never saved to the Docker file system. I can run the below code locally and the file gets saved without issue. When I run the below code in a Docker container, the file is never written to the storage folder.

```
    $loc = storage_path('app/rovi/');

    $remote_file = $directory . $m->remoteFileName . $yesterday . '_Full.zip';

    // get zip file
    $zip_file = Storage::disk('ftp')->get($remote_file);

    $this->info($zip_file);

    $this->info('Download file received...');

    Storage::disk('local')->put( $m->fileNameZip . '.zip', $zip_file);
```

Docker file

```
FROM nielsvdoorn/docker-alpine-laravel:latest

RUN apk update

RUN pecl install mongodb \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

 RUN apk add zlib-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-zlib-dir=/usr \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip


RUN apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.6.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN apk add curl-dev
RUN apk add libxml2-dev

RUN printf "xdebug.remote_autostart=1\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN printf "xdebug.remote_enable=1\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN printf "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN printf "xdebug.remote_mode=req\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN printf "xdebug.remote_host=92.168.1.118\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN printf "xdebug.remote_port=9000\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN printf "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1\n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN printf "memory_limit=512M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# for confirmation
RUN cat /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN php -i | grep xdebug.remote

COPY ./usr /usr

COPY . /var/www/html

RUN apk add --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
COPY ./rancher/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

RUN chown -R root:root /var/www/html/storage
RUN chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/storage
```

The file is never saved with the Storage::disk put and I have changed the owner to root and permissions to 777 for testing. Still no luck. No errors in laravel logs

Comment: Are logs being written? What error messages are you seeing? Without your Dockerfile, it's hard to know for sure, but I'd imagine it's a permissions issue.

Comment: I ended up using file_put_contents and I was able to save the file. I wish Storage::put was able to give more detailed errors on failing to save.